Setting string variable after an if statement
After I set a string variable in an if() statement, the variable does not exist.
if (wallThicknessCBO.SelectedItem.ToString() == "2x6")
{
    if (wallH <= 8)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("2x6 and 8");
        string w_Prod_Code = "2608STUD";
        MessageBox.Show(w_Prod_Code);//messagebox shows w_Prod_Code
    }

}

//MessageBox.Show(w_Prod_Code); //says w_Prod_code does not exist

I attempted this at the beginning of the method, but the 2nd message box just shows up as blank.
string w_Prod_Code = "";
public void WallThickness()

What would I need to do to use the string variable from the if statement?

Is the real question why you only see the "" stored in the w_Prod_Code field, instead of the variable's value? That's because you defined two different things with the same name, a field and a variable. When in scope, the variable hides the field. There's probably an Intellisense warning or Info message saying the variable hides the field. Use w_Prod_Code = "2608STUD"; to assign the field instead of declaring a variable

Change
string w_Prod_Code = "2608STUD";

to only
w_Prod_Code = "2608STUD";

or better yet
this.w_Prod_Code = "2608STUD";

Right now the question's code defines two different things named w_Prod_Code:

A field w_Prod_Code whose value never changes from "" and
A variable defined inside a nested loop, that isn't visible outside the block it was declared in. The variable hides the field in its scope

There's probably an Intellisense or Resharper message warning that the variable is hiding the field.
It's a very good idea to use different naming for variables and fields. If you intend to use the same names, make sure you use this. to refer to fields, eg this.prod_code.

Many C# developers start the name of fields with an underscore to avoid confusion with parameters or variables. E.g.: private string _wProdCode = "";

@OlivierJacot-Descombes me too, along with half of MS's own repos and ReSharper. I don't want to get into that religious war right now.

This was intended as a practical tip for the OP.
